# Searching public profiles using Facebook Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am looking to search Facebook public profiles using the Graph API with parameters like name, location and age. To accomplish this I created a Facebook app to get an app ID but I am unsure as to how to proceed to make the query to the API.

To try it out I tried using the explorer (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/) but I am unable to get any results that does not contain "me". I made sure to get a access token and enter a query like the following:

```
search?q=tobias&type=user&fields=id,name
```

The only reply is:

```
{
   "data": [
   ]
}
```

I feel like I am missing something but I have been unable to figure out what, please advice.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/breaking-changes#search-4-4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The search endpoint is broken since 2018-04-04 for certain search types, including pages and users.

> Search API
>
> You can no longer use the /search endpoint with the following object types:
>
> - event
> - group
> - page
> - user

See
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/breaking-changes#search-4-4

Answer (score 0):

Due to what has recently been in the news, searching for users has been deprecated, and is not supported through Facebook APIs.